# WebGL vec4() description

Tags: glsl, webgl

I am just learning WebGL graphics programming.

I am examining someone's code that includes the statement

```c
// multiply the position by the matrix.
gl_Position = vec4((u_matrix * vec3(a_position,1)).xy,0,1);
```

I think he is multiplying a 4-component vector by a 4x4 matrix.  But unsure why/what the `.xy` is?

If someone could tell me what is happening here and where to go for `vec4()` definition page?

Comment: I believe this snippet comes from https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is called swizzling in the shader code. It's a convenient way offered by the language to access the components of a vector. There are different accessors defined, matching with the syntax need: rgba, xyzw, stpq.

You can find more information on https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling

```
vec4 aVector;
vec4 color = aVector.rgba;
vec4 coordinates = aVector.xyzw;
vec4 textures = aVector.stpq;
```

But you can also play the way you want with this accessors to create vectors of different dimensions, or use the components in the order you need.

```
vec4 point;
vec2 projected = point.xy;
vec2 orthogonal = point.yx;

vec4 aVector;
vec2 textureCoord = aVector.st;

vec4 color;
vec3 grayscale = color.rrr;

vec3 colorRGB;
vec3 colorBGR = colorRGB.bgr;
```

In your case gl_Position is a vec4 built-in in the vertex shader built-in that should be set with a 4 dimension clip space vector.

Your code transforms the 2D vertex attribute a_position into the 4D clip space value.

```
gl_Position = vec4((u_matrix * vec3(a_position,1)).xy,0,1);
```

Let's rewrite this code to have a better understanding

```
// First create a vector 3 and assign a_position xy components, and z component to 1
vec3 position = vec3(a_position, 1.0);

// Transform the point with the 3D matrix
vec3 transformed = u_matrix * position;

// Set the clip space vec4 with the transformed position x and y components
// Set z to 0 and w to 1
gl_Position = vec4(transformed.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: In the page that the snippet comes from (https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html), `a_position` is a vec2, which is why `vec3(a_position, 1.0)` works.

Answer (score 2):

To understand `.xy` you have to read about [Swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling). `.xy` gets the `x` and `y` component of `a_position` and creates a `vec2` with this components.

In glsl vectors (`vec2`, `vec3`, `vec4`) can be constructed in many different ways. See [Vector constructors](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Vector_constructors). Thus a `vec4` can be constructed by a `vec2` and 2 scalars.

`gl_Position = vec4((u_matrix * vec3(a_position,1)).xy,0,1);` can be expressed as:

```c
vec3 pos_vec3             = vec3(a_position, 1);
vec3 pos_vec3_transformed = u_matrix * pos_vec3;
vec2 pos_vec2             = pos_vec3_transformed.xy;
vec4 pos_vec4             = vec4(pos_vec2, 0, 1);

gl_Position = pos_vec4;
```

Explanation:

`a_position` is of type `vec2` and `u_matrix` is of type `mat3`, thus `a_position` has to be expanded to `vec3` to perform a multiplication of `u_matrix` and `a_position`:

```c
vec3 pos_vec3             = vec3(a_position, 1);
vec3 pos_vec3_transformed = u_matrix * pos_vec3;
```

Furthermore, only the components `x` and `y` are required, thus the `z` component is skipped:

```c
vec2 pos_vec2 = pos_vec3_transformed.xy;
```

`gl_Position` is of type `vec4`, thus the transformed position has to be expanded to a `vec4`:

```c
vec4 pos_vec4 = vec4(pos_vec2, 0, 1);
gl_Position   = pos_vec4;
```